# How to call a function from models.py with class based views in Django?

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, django-class-based-views

I would like to convert a user uploaded .docx file to .html using a function/method I have in models.py. I can do it with function based view with this kind of approach:

models.py:

```
class Article(models.Model):
    main_file = models.FileField(upload_to="files")
    slug = models.UUIDField(primary_key=True, default=uuid.uuid4, editable=False)

    @classmethod
    def convert_word(self, slug):
        import pypandoc
        pypandoc.convert_file('media/files/%s.docx' %slug, 'html', outputfile="media/files/%s.html" %slug)
```

And then I call the convert_word function like this in views.py:

```
def submission_conf_view(request, slug):
    Article.convert_word(slug)
    return redirect('submission:article_list')
```

What I would like to do is to call the same function/method but using Django's Class-based views, but I am having trouble figuring that out.

Answer (score 1):

You could use the base `View` and override the `get` method.

```
from django.views import View

class MyView(view):
    def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        Article.convert_word(self.kwargs['slug'])
        return redirect('submission:article_list')
```

Or since your view always redirects, you could use `RedirectView`.

```
class MyView(RedirectView):

    permanent = False
    pattern_name = 'submission:article_list'  # the pattern to redirect to

    def get_redirect_url(self, *args, **kwargs):
        # call the model method
        Article.convert_word(self.kwargs['slug'])
        # call super() to return a redirect
        return super().get_redirect_url(*args, **kwargs)
```

However there's not real advantage to using either of these. I think your current three line method is more readable.

See the docs about [an introduction to class based views](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/topics/class-based-views/intro/#using-class-based-views) or [`RedirectView`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/class-based-views/base/#redirectview) for more info.